# How to share songs from Groove?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sharing, groove

Groove music is ultimately the best music playing app for Windows phone and can easily do most of  the needed features. However it doesn't seem to allow me to share music tracks directly from the app. Long pressing a track produces a pop-up menu but it also does not contain share option. Every time I want to share a song I have to locate it manually to send it via file explorer app. So my question is that is there anyway to share a song directly form Groove app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is Share option present in Groove**

Yes there is a share option built into the Groove music player. But, the share option in Groove is a URL/link sharing option and not a file sharing option. Below is the changelog related to this option, when the feature arrived to Groove in version 3.6.2142

> Copy links to songs, albums, and artists right in the app so you can easily share music with anyone, anywhere.

**When is this option usefull?**

- When you are in a region where Groove Music services is present
- When you want to share the song details on FB, Twitter, Whatsapp, Hike, etc...

**What if I want to share the .mp3 file?**

There is no built-in option for that. MS is most unlikely to bring that option as it may support piracy. You can use other apps like SHARE.it or share using File explorer.

**Why am I not seeing it?**

It will only be avialable if you are present in a region where Groove services are located. Here is the [list of countires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groove_Music#Geographical_availability) supported according to Wikipedia.

**References**

- [MSPoweruser - Groove Music to add sharing features](https://mspoweruser.com/groove-music-amobile-devices/)
- [Windows Central - Groove Music update brings easier sharing and more](http://www.windowscentral.com/groove-music-updated-fast-ring-insiders-top-artist-radio-stations-more)
- [Wikipedia - Geographical availability of Groove Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groove_Music#Geographical_availability)

**Screenshots**

[image: Share option in Groove]

Comment: So, the bottom line is Groove does not support sharing of mp3 files. Right?

Comment: @User5 Yes. And it may **never**, due to it's cloud based link sharing feature.